# How can I create a column in R counting a group's order of appearance

Tags: r, aggregate

I want to create the column Counter

```
Name Counter
John 0
John 1
John 1
Kate 0
Kate 1
Kate 2
Kate 3
```

If I used SAS I would write:

```
if FIRST.Smoking_Status 
  Count = 0;              
Count + 1;                

run;
```

If every name is supposed to be a group, I have 3000 groups.

Comment: Is line 3 intended to be 2?

Comment: `library(dplyr); your_table %>% group_by(Name) %>% mutate(Counter = row_number() - 1)`

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Yes line 3 intended to be 2. Though your answer seems to work according the comments in Console, the column "counter" is not created in the file

Comment: Assign that chain to an object to save it. To update the existing table, assign the output to the source table, i.e. `your_table <- your_table %>% group_by(Name) %>% mutate(Counter = row_number() - 1)` or `your_table %>% group_by(Name) %>% mutate(Counter = row_number() - 1) -> your_table`

Comment: Thank you so much !!! I realized it after replying!